# How to compile only JSX and imports and not ES6 code?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using react-scripts, and i'd like to leave all es6 code as it is, for debugging purpose. For example, my browser could understand arrow functions, generators, async await and classes (we use these features a lot), but I need jsx compilation. Besides, when all code is packed into bundle.js, there is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import", so I need to compile "import" and "export" statements, because we also use that:

```
import {func} from "module";
export * from "module";
```

I know that there are source maps, and they do really help, but after all it  sometimes gets hard to execute code step by step in debugger and play around in console, while on breakpoint.

Comment: I think `export * from "module"` is invalid syntax, you probably want to use `export * as SomeModule from "module"`

Comment: @corvid we use that, when we need module to export all content of it's submodules. Actually that code is quite common in our project. I dont know what standard it is, but it's correctly working with 'react-script' default configuration (which compiles that code in pure es5)

Comment: You probably just want Babel with the React preset and the `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` plugin.